# How to amend defined function to calculate wanted output (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics, data-analysis

I am trying to calculate the following 'new_field' column by triple looping through the 'name', 'val_id' and 'fac_id' column with the following conditions.

1.Within each 'val_id' loop if 'product' == 'CL' then min of 'val_against' and 'our_val_amt' e.g. min( val_against (134), our_val_amt (424)) therefore 'NEW FIELD' = 134. Also if the sum of new_field exceeds "our_val_amt", then subtract it from "our_val_amt". e.g. for val_id "xx4", (200 + 300 + 50) = 550 which exceeds our_val_amt = 510, so NEW FILED = 510 - 500 (i.e. 200 + 300 after this sum exceeds our_val_amt) = 10.

2.If product != 'CL' and is in the same 'val_id' group. The remainder to be subtracted from 'our_val_amt' to be inserted in 'new_field'. e.g 'our_val_amt' (424) - from step 1 (134) = 290. This inserted above 'NEW FIELD'.

If [product] doesn't have 'CL' it just needs to spread the [our_val_amt] between each [val_id]. For example val_id = 'xx7' our_val_amt =700 this is spread in the first row (650) inserted and then left over 700 - 650 = 50 is inserted in next row with the following being 0 as per the example.

3.Repeat steps for val_id xx2. NEW FIELD calculation for CL = 104 and XL = 472 - 104 = 368.

Currently the output works correctly for 'name' - compx(row 0 - 9) and begins to not correctly calculate onwards. I'm also unsure how this code works as i'm new to Pandas and appreciate if someone can explain the defined function how the program is thinking.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["compx","xx1","yy1",424,418,"XL"],["compx","xx1","yy2",424,134,"CL"],["compx","xx2","yy3",472,60,"DL"],["compx","xx2","yy4",472,104,"CL"], ["compx", "xx3", "yy5", 490, 50, "XL"], ["compx", "xx3", "yy6", 490, 500, "CL"], ["compx", "xx3", "yy7", 490, 200, "DL"], ["compx", "xx4", "yy8", 510, 200, "CL"], ["compx", "xx4", "yy9", 510, 300, "CL"], ["compx", "xx4", "yy10", 510, 50, "CL"], ["compy", "xx5", "yy11", 510, 200, "CL"], ["compy", "xx5", "yy12", 510, 300, "CL"], ["compy", "xx5", "yy12", 510, 50, "CL"], ["compy", "xx5", "yy13", 510, 30, "DL"], ["compz", "xx6", "yy14", 350, 200, "CL"], ["compz", "xx6", "yy15", 350, 100, "CL"], ["compz", "xx6", "yy16", 350, 50, "XL"], ["compz", "xx6", "yy17", 350, 50, "DL"], ["compz", "xx7", "yy18", 700, 650, "DL"], ["compz", "xx7", "yy19", 700, 200, "DL"], ["compz", "xx7", "yy20", 700, 400, "XL"] ], columns=["name","val_id","fac_id","our_val_amt","val_against","product"])
df


# Compute tuple of "our_val_amt", "val_against" and "product" for easy processing as one column. It is hard to process multiple columns with "transform()".
df["the_tuple"] = df[["our_val_amt", "val_against", "product"]].apply(tuple, axis=1)

def compute_new_field_for_cl(g):
  # df_g is a tuple ("our_val_amt", "val_against", "product") indexed as (0, 1, 2).
  df_g = g.apply(pd.Series)
  df_g["new_field"] = df_g.apply(lambda row: min(row[0], row[1]) if row[2] == "CL" else 0, axis=1)
  df_g["cumsum"] = df_g["new_field"].cumsum()
  df_g["new_field"] = df_g.apply(lambda row: 0 if row["cumsum"] > row[0] else row["new_field"], axis=1)
  df_g["max_cumsum"] = df_g["new_field"].cumsum()
  df_g["new_field"] = df_g.apply(lambda row: row[0] - row["max_cumsum"] if row["cumsum"] > row[0] else row["new_field"], axis=1)
  return df_g["new_field"]

# Apply above function and compute new field values for "CL".
df["new_field"] = df.groupby("val_id")[["the_tuple"]].transform(compute_new_field_for_cl)

# Re-compute tuple of "our_val_amt", "new_field" and "product".
df["the_tuple"] = df[["our_val_amt", "new_field", "product"]].apply(tuple, axis=1)

def compute_new_field_for_not_cl(g):
  # df_g is a tuple ("our_val_amt", "new_field", "product") indexed as (0, 1, 2).
  df_g = g.apply(pd.Series)
  result_sr = df_g.where(df_g[2] != "CL")[0] - df_g[df_g[2] == "CL"][1].sum()
  result_sr = result_sr.fillna(0) + df_g[1]
  return result_sr

# Apply above function and compute new field values for "CL".
df["new_field"] = df.groupby("val_id")[["the_tuple"]].transform(compute_new_field_for_not_cl)

df = df.drop("the_tuple", axis=1)
df
```

Dataset and new_field output trying to achieve.

```
name    |val_id |fac_id     |   our_val_amt |   val_against |   product |   new_field
compx   |   xx1 |   yy1     |   424         |   418         |   XL      |   290
compx   |   xx1 |   yy2     |   424         |   134         |   CL      |   134
compx   |   xx2 |   yy3     |   472         |   60          |   DL      |   368
compx   |   xx2 |   yy4     |   472         |   104         |   CL      |   104
compx   |   xx3 |   yy5     |   490         |   50          |   XL      |   0
compx   |   xx3 |   yy6     |   490         |   500         |   CL      |   490
compx   |   xx3 |   yy7     |   490         |   200         |   DL      |   0
compx   |   xx4 |   yy8     |   510         |   200         |   CL      |   200
compx   |   xx4 |   yy9     |   510         |   300         |   CL      |   300
compx   |   xx4 |   yy10    |   510         |   50          |   CL      |   10
compy   |   xx5 |   yy11    |   510         |   200         |   CL      |   200
compy   |   xx5 |   yy12    |   510         |   300         |   CL      |   300
compy   |   xx5 |   yy12    |   510         |   50          |   CL      |   10
compy   |   xx5 |   yy13    |   510         |   30          |   DL      |   0
compz   |   xx6 |   yy14    |   350         |   200         |   CL      |   200
compz   |   xx6 |   yy15    |   350         |   100         |   CL      |   100
compz   |   xx6 |   yy16    |   350         |   50          |   XL      |   50
compz   |   xx6 |   yy17    |   350         |   50          |   DL      |   0
compz   |   xx7 |   yy18    |   700         |   650         |   DL      |   650
compz   |   xx7 |   yy19    |   700         |   200         |   DL      |   50
compz   |   xx7 |   yy20    |   700         |   400         |   XL      |   0
```

Dataset and new_field output that i'm currently getting

```
name    |val_id |fac_id     |   our_val_amt |   val_against |   product |   new_field
compx   |   xx1 |   yy1     |   424         |   418         |   XL      |   290
compx   |   xx1 |   yy2     |   424         |   134         |   CL      |   134
compx   |   xx2 |   yy3     |   472         |   60          |   DL      |   368
compx   |   xx2 |   yy4     |   472         |   104         |   CL      |   104
compx   |   xx3 |   yy5     |   490         |   50          |   XL      |   0
compx   |   xx3 |   yy6     |   490         |   500         |   CL      |   490
compx   |   xx3 |   yy7     |   490         |   200         |   DL      |   0
compx   |   xx4 |   yy8     |   510         |   200         |   CL      |   200
compx   |   xx4 |   yy9     |   510         |   300         |   CL      |   300
compx   |   xx4 |   yy10    |   510         |   50          |   CL      |   10
compy   |   xx5 |   yy11    |   510         |   200         |   CL      |   200
compy   |   xx5 |   yy12    |   510         |   300         |   CL      |   300
compy   |   xx5 |   yy12    |   510         |   50          |   CL      |   10
compy   |   xx5 |   yy13    |   510         |   30          |   DL      |   10
compz   |   xx6 |   yy14    |   350         |   200         |   CL      |   200
compz   |   xx6 |   yy15    |   350         |   100         |   CL      |   100
compz   |   xx6 |   yy16    |   350         |   50          |   XL      |   50
compz   |   xx6 |   yy17    |   350         |   50          |   DL      |   50
compz   |   xx7 |   yy18    |   700         |   650         |   DL      |   700
compz   |   xx7 |   yy19    |   700         |   200         |   DL      |   700
compz   |   xx7 |   yy20    |   700         |   400         |   XL      |   700
```

Comment: Your explanation conflicts with expected values (650, 50, 0) for val_id="xx7". In the description, you expect `new_field` values to be subtracted from `our_val_amt` if  product !="CL"; but in expected output you have not subtracted anything from 700; but instead copied `val_against`. This is not clear. How do you compute values for xx7?

Comment: Hi Azhar, sorry for the confusion. I do expect this to occur if the product 'CL' is within the [val_id]. The example for val_id = 'xx7' doesn't have a [product] = 'CL'.
If [product] doesn't have 'CL' it just needs to spread the [our_val_amt]  between each  [val_id]. For example val_id = 'xx7' our_val_amt =700 this is spread in the first row (650) inserted and then left over 700 - 650 = 50 is inserted in next row with the following being 0 as per the example.

Comment: Actually sorry you're looking at what the code is outputting. Please look at "Dataset and new_field output trying to achieve."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code failed at a corner case where there are multiple non-CL products and the `our_val_amt` had to be spread such that last few products may get `0` value. I asked about this use case in last/preceding question; but it went unanswered. You may have some corner cases like this and need to perform a comprehensive test.

Following is the updated logic. The comments are added before each processing line to explain what it does.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["compx","xx1","yy2",424,134,"CL",134],["compx","xx1","yy1",424,418,"XL",290],["compx","xx2","yy4",472,104,"CL",104],["compx","xx2","yy3",472,60,"DL",368],["compx","xx3","yy6",490,500,"CL",490],["compx","xx3","yy5",490,50,"XL",0],["compx","xx3","yy7",490,200,"DL",0],["compx","xx4","yy8",510,200,"CL",200],["compx","xx4","yy9",510,300,"CL",300],["compx","xx4","yy10",510,50,"CL",10],["compy","xx5","yy11",510,200,"CL",200],["compy","xx5","yy12",510,300,"CL",300],["compy","xx5","yy12",510,50,"CL",10],["compy","xx5","yy13",510,30,"DL",0],["compz","xx6","yy14",350,200,"CL",200],["compz","xx6","yy15",350,100,"CL",100],["compz","xx6","yy16",350,50,"XL",50],["compz","xx6","yy17",350,50,"DL",0],["compz","xx7","yy18",700,650,"DL",650],["compz","xx7","yy19",700,200,"DL",50],["compz","xx7","yy20",700,400,"XL",0]], columns=["name","val_id","fac_id","our_val_amt","val_against","product","new_field_expected"])


# Compute tuple of "our_val_amt", "val_against" and "product" for easy processing as one column. It is hard to process multiple columns with "transform()".
df["the_tuple"] = df[["our_val_amt", "val_against", "product"]].apply(tuple, axis=1)

def compute_new_field_for_cl(g):
  # df_g is a tuple ("our_val_amt", "val_against", "product") indexed as (0, 1, 2).
  df_g = g.apply(pd.Series)
  df_g["new_field"] = df_g.apply(lambda row: min(row[0], row[1]) if row[2] == "CL" else 0, axis=1)
  # Cumulative sum for comparison
  df_g["cumsum"] = df_g["new_field"].cumsum()
  # Previous row's sum for comparison
  df_g["cumsum_prev"] = df_g["cumsum"].shift(periods=1)
  # if our_val_amt >= sum then use min(our_val_amt, val_against)
  # else if our_val_amt < sum then take partial of first record such that our_val_amt == sum else take `0` for the rest records
  df_g["new_field"] = df_g.apply(lambda row: 0 if row["cumsum_prev"] > row[0] else row[0] - row["cumsum_prev"] if row["cumsum"] > row[0] else row["new_field"], axis=1)
  return df_g["new_field"]

# Apply above function and compute new field values for "CL".
df["new_field"] = df.groupby("val_id")[["the_tuple"]].transform(compute_new_field_for_cl)


# Re-compute tuple of "our_val_amt", "val_against", "new_field" and "product".
df["the_tuple"] = df[["our_val_amt", "val_against", "new_field", "product"]].apply(tuple, axis=1)

def compute_new_field_for_not_cl(g):
  # df_g is a tuple ("our_val_amt", "val_against", "new_field", "product") indexed as (0, 1, 2, 3).
  df_g = g.apply(pd.Series)
  # print(df_g)
  cl_sum = df_g[df_g[3] == "CL"][2].sum()
  if cl_sum > 0:
    df_g["new_field"] = df_g.where(df_g[3] != "CL")[0] - df_g[df_g[3] == "CL"][2].sum()
    df_g["new_field"] = df_g["new_field"].fillna(df_g[2])
    # Cumulative sum for comparison
    df_g["cumsum"] = df_g["new_field"].cumsum()
    # if our_val_amt < sum then take diff (our_val_amt - sum) else take `0` for the rest records
    df_g["new_field"] = df_g.apply(lambda row: 0 if row["cumsum"] > row[0] else row["new_field"], axis=1)
  else:
    df_g["new_field"] = df_g.apply(lambda row: min(row[0], row[1]) if row[3] != "CL" else row[2], axis=1)
    # Cumulative sum for comparison
    df_g["cumsum"] = df_g["new_field"].cumsum()
    # Previous row's sum for comparison
    df_g["cumsum_prev"] = df_g["cumsum"].shift(periods=1)
    # if our_val_amt >= sum then use min(our_val_amt, val_against)
    # else if our_val_amt < sum then take partial of first record such that our_val_amt == sum else take `0` for the rest records
    df_g["new_field"] = df_g.apply(lambda row: 0 if row["cumsum_prev"] > row[0] else row[0] - row["cumsum_prev"] if row["cumsum"] > row[0] else row["new_field"], axis=1)

  return df_g["new_field"]

# Apply above function and compute new field values for "CL".
df["new_field"] = df.groupby("val_id")[["the_tuple"]].transform(compute_new_field_for_not_cl)


df = df.drop("the_tuple", axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     name val_id fac_id  our_val_amt  val_against product  new_field_expected  new_field
0   compx    xx1    yy2          424          134      CL                 134     134.00
1   compx    xx1    yy1          424          418      XL                 290     290.00
2   compx    xx2    yy4          472          104      CL                 104     104.00
3   compx    xx2    yy3          472           60      DL                 368     368.00
4   compx    xx3    yy6          490          500      CL                 490     490.00
5   compx    xx3    yy5          490           50      XL                   0       0.00
6   compx    xx3    yy7          490          200      DL                   0       0.00
7   compx    xx4    yy8          510          200      CL                 200     200.00
8   compx    xx4    yy9          510          300      CL                 300     300.00
9   compx    xx4   yy10          510           50      CL                  10      10.00
10  compy    xx5   yy11          510          200      CL                 200     200.00
11  compy    xx5   yy12          510          300      CL                 300     300.00
12  compy    xx5   yy12          510           50      CL                  10      10.00
13  compy    xx5   yy13          510           30      DL                   0       0.00
14  compz    xx6   yy14          350          200      CL                 200     200.00
15  compz    xx6   yy15          350          100      CL                 100     100.00
16  compz    xx6   yy16          350           50      XL                  50      50.00
17  compz    xx6   yy17          350           50      DL                   0       0.00
18  compz    xx7   yy18          700          650      DL                 650     650.00
19  compz    xx7   yy19          700          200      DL                  50      50.00
20  compz    xx7   yy20          700          400      XL                   0       0.00
```

Comment: Referring to elsewhere. If one of your posts gets deleted and you disagree you should be able to flag for moderator attention. Did you do that?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you are saying. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: One of your other posts was deleted and you objected to the comment which preceded that. I just wanted to tell you that you can flag for moderator attention to get the (possibly) undone. Also I want to know whether you did. From what I can tell, there was an accident today with one of your deleted posts. Feel free to review there.